# Filter data with AngularJS from JSON file

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-filter

I am creating a "word of the day" functionality in a web app and I have a JSON file with the following data structure. I couldn't get myself to dump 730+ entries into the HTML under `ng-init` to filter by `day`.

`{"words":[
    {
      "day":"0",
      "aramaic":"mi<u>t</u>ra",
      "english":"rain"
    },
    {
      "day":"1",
      "aramaic":"libba",
      "english":"heart"
    }]
}`

I have the JSON file being called in the controller and trying to bring it in via scope.

```
$http.get('content/words.json').success(function(data) {
    var pairNum, prevPage, nextPage;    
    pairNum = 1;

        $scope.word = {
            all:data,
            day:parseInt(data.words[pairNum]["day"]),
            eng:data.words[pairNum]["english"],
            cha:data.words[pairNum]["aramaic"],
            limit:data.words.length
        }   

});
```

To my demise, I am unable to bring the JSON data to the HTML via `$scope.word.all` to filter. I would greatly appreciate help here, or a different way to architect this solution if I am approaching it wrong.

Here is how the HTML looks

```
<div class="row" ng-init="words = word.all">
<h2>CHALDEAN WORD OF THE DAY</h2>
<div class="small-2 columns"><a ng-click="word.day = word.day - 1"><span ng-show="word.day > 1" class="foundicon-left-arrow"> &nbsp;<span></a></div>
<div class="small-8 columns" ng-repeat="word in words | filter:word.day"><h4 class="wotd">{{word.english}} :: {{word.chaldean}} :: {{word.day}}<h4></div>
<div class="small-2 columns"><a ng-click="word.day = word.day + 1"><span ng-show="word.day < word.limit" class="foundicon-right-arrow"> &nbsp;<span></a></div></div><!-- .row -->
```

Thank you in advance to all that will attempt.

Ps. I already have a feeling I will be screwed with the `<u>` in the JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look here : **[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/xcgD56KBwQYeln1QQpXG?p=preview)**

html:

```
      <h2>CHALDEAN WORD OF THE DAY</h2>
    <div class="small-2 columns">
    <a ng-click="pairNum = pairNum -1">
    <span ng-show="pairNum > 0" class="foundicon-left-arrow"> previous <span></a></div>

    <div class="small-8 columns" ng-repeat="w in word | filter:{day:pairNum} ">
    <h4 class="wotd">
      {{w.english}} :
    : {{w.aramaic}} :
    : {{w.day}}
    <h4>

    </div>
    <div class="small-2 columns">
    <a ng-click="pairNum = pairNum + 1">
    <span ng-show="pairNum < word.limit-1" class="foundicon-right-arrow"> next <span></a>

</div></div><!-- .row -->
```

js:

```
    var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.pairNum = 0;
    $scope.words = [];

    $http.get('content/words.json').success(function(data) {

     angular.copy(data, $scope.words );

     });

});
```

Comment: Thank you, but the missing piece is still how to connect the JSON file to the scope. I am anticipating around 730 words.